# What is the best practice to manage dynamic JavaScript from Java?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, markerclusterer

I am developing a webpage in JSP which uses a big ammount of dynamically generated JavaScript code from a Java backend class. It is about Google Maps and a JS library called MarkerClusterer.

Currently this class is generating the JavaScript code by handling Strings in Java and printing it directly into the JSP page, but it's getting a little bit complicated to write JS within Java String and maintain that.

The JavaScript requires a lot of modifications all the time, as this class is being used in different projects. Ideally I would like to package this in a way it could be used as a library, not requiring further modifications, so that's the question, what is the best way to do that?

Here's a part of the code:

```
public class JavascriptGenerator {

    public String gerarPorRegiao(String contextPath, List<Endereco> lista, boolean infoWindowEnabled) {
        String saida = "";

        saida += "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false\"></script>"
                + "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\""
                + contextPath
                + "/js/markerclusterer.js\"></script>"
                + "<script type=\"text/javascript\">"
                + "var map;";
        for(Estado e: Estado.values()) {
            saida += "var mc" + e.toString() + ";";
        }
                saida += "var selecionado;"
                + "var center = new google.maps.LatLng(-11.0, -51.9);"
                + "var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();"
                + "var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();"
                + "var markerContent = new Array();"
                + "function geocoderInit() {"
...
```

Comment: There is never a *best* way to do something. Only the way which works best for *you*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say: don't.

Don't generate javascript dynamically. It will be a nightmare to maintain. Keep your js in a static file, and use ajax to fetch your data. Your data can be in the form of JSON. JSON can be auto-generated from an object hierarchy using one of many JSON libs you can download.

Comment: This seems like a good and elegant choice in theory - except when you try to implement this in practice :) If you have several jQuery UI elements on the page of moderate complexity (several jQuery datatables, and Select2, and ..), and they all start to download the data using AJAX, the result is that you see a page which "gradually" comes to life - fisrt this datatable, then that, then the select "finds" its options, then.. "User experience" suffers and the complete page appears to load slowly..

Comment: I don't agree and it is widely known that a page will appear faster to humans if something is happening on the page. But the core of my answer is to use a json lib to render the data. If you wish you can just put a json blob in a script tag. It will be no more difficult to maintain.

Comment: "If you wish you can just put a json blob in a script tag" -  you can (in jsp) create a custom tag which outputs your json in suitable places in the <script>...</script> section in a javascript format. Is this what you suggest, or you were thinking of something simpler?

Answer (score 1):

one thing you can do is , use a string buffer and add all you java script stuff into it.
Then write it a file with .js as extension. so, this makes your script maintainable

Answer (score 1):

You could write a separate JSP file that creates the javascript. Then all static parts of the Javascript would be as usual:

```
var map;

<% for(Estado e: Eastado.values()) { %>
var mc<%=e.toString()%>;
<% } %>

var selecionado;
...
```

This JSP can then be loaded by the HTML page your other JSP creates:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="path/to/jsp/file.jsp"></script>
```

If your script needs access to data, you could pass parameters via URL:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="path/to/jsp/file.jsp?id=15"></script>
```

Then, in the script, in a filter or anything similar, you can directly use these parameters or use them to load data from a database or so.

Comment: I was thinking about something like this too, but how to pass the variables the method needs to a page? Maybe I can use `SESSION` or `POST` instead?

Comment: Don't know what you mean by SESSION and POST. Won't work I think. You can pass URL parameters to the JSP: path/to/jsp/file.jsp?id=17

Comment: I did the way you said, except that I used `SESSION`, as it support passing Objects. The URL parameters that you referred is called `GET`, and along with `SESSION` and `POST`, it's one of the three ways of passing data from one page to another in web programming. If you want to know more about it, read here, it's a PHP article, but every web language have this: [link](http://www.royhochstenbach.com/php-passing-information-http-post-vs-http-get-vs-sessions-vs-cookies/)

Comment: Putting your data in the session means holding it serverside. That means you might get problems if the user opens multiple browser tabs as all tabs share one session then. POST is out of scope as the <script>-tag always loads the javascript file via HTTP GET.